# How to obtain only specific values from a nested JSON response from a Google API?

Tags: python, json, api, qgis, google-geocoding-api

I am building a reverse geocoding plugin for QGIS, and need to read only specific fields (e.g. only the postal code) from a JSON file. The JSON is the response to a Google Geolocation API call, and is of the following format:

```
"results" : [
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "10",
           "short_name" : "10",
           "types" : [ "street_number" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Λεωφόρος Δημοκρατίας",
           "short_name" : "Λεωφ. Δημοκρατίας",
           "types" : [ "route" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Πεύκα",
           "short_name" : "Πεύκα",
           "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Θεσσαλονίκη",
           "short_name" : "Θεσσαλονίκη",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_3", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Ελλάδα",
           "short_name" : "GR",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "570 10",
           "short_name" : "570 10",
           "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
        }
     ],
```

I am parsing the JSON file using the json.loads(...) method in python, but it seems that python recognises it as list.

UPDATE: After reviewing your answers, I found the solution thank you everyone!

```
for item in results[0]["address_components"]: 
    if item["types"] == ["route"]:
      a = item["long_name"]
```

results is the list parsed from "results", and it is accessed through the above code. 
a captures the value of the string carrying the "route" name.

Comment: It *is* a list. You would need to iterate through it and select only those entries that you consider relevant.

Comment: Of course, it is a list. Your "results" is a list of objects with "address_components" whereas "address_components" is again a list of objects.

Comment: when I try to obtain the 5th feature in the ''address_components'' list, I get a KeyError, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```py
p={"results" : [
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "10",
           "short_name" : "10",
           "types" : [ "street_number" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Λεωφόρος Δημοκρατίας",
           "short_name" : "Λεωφ. Δημοκρατίας",
           "types" : [ "route" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Πεύκα",
           "short_name" : "Πεύκα",
           "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Θεσσαλονίκη",
           "short_name" : "Θεσσαλονίκη",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_3", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Ελλάδα",
           "short_name" : "GR",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "570 10",
           "short_name" : "570 10",
           "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
        }
     ]
     }
]
}
for item in p["results"][0]["address_components"]:
  if item["long_name"]=="570 10":

    print(item["types"])
```

Comment: Convert the result to a dictionary with a list..Loop through it accordingly

Comment: In addition to that, you can use indices to loop through the list

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through `results` which is a list. If you want to get 5th element you can do it like this:

```
results[0]['address_components'][4]
```

If you want to get element from list use `[id]` (replace `id` with element number) and if you want to get value from dictionary use `'key'` (replace `key` with name)

Comment: I tried using the structure you mentioned, but I am getting a ''List index out of range error'' (reffering to the [4] )

Comment: Can you create pastebin link (https://pastebin.com/) with your code, or edit your question to include your code please? It will be easier to see what's going on instead of having json response only.